# How to escape the word "todo"

Tags: ide, comments, phpstorm, todo

I have a comment:

```
// ... see "todo" below
```

PhpStorm thinks I have a TODO that says "below".

How can I escape it? I prefer an IDE-agnostic solution.

Thanks

Comment: Change the comment to something that doesn't use an IDE keyword.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to escape it, so I would personally opt for _todo or \_todo\_

Comment: You can also change the TODO pattern so it only recongizes upper case or with spaces around it or with colon after it... it's all in the tutorial: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Working+with+todo+comments+and+the+todo+tool+window

Comment: @Carcigenicate using `to-do` seems to be viable

Answer (score 3):

You can configure your TODO patterns here:

```
Settings > Editor > TODO
```

If you want to keep using `todo` for marking tasks, you can change the `todo` pattern into `TODO` and mark it as case sensitive (so only upper-case `TODO` will lead to marking a task).

If you don't want to use it, just delete or change it into something else.